# Display gif inside NSImageView - Swift 3 - Mac

Tags: swift, gif, nsimageview

I am trying to load and display a gif file inside a NSImageView but nothing appears when I run the project.

I have try to link the gif file with NSImageView using url, data or named, but it does not work.

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
 let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "RSynchro-Gif", withExtension: "gif")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        gifBoutton.image = NSImage(data: data)
}
```

or

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "RSynchro-Gif", withExtension: "gif")!
        gifBoutton.image = try! NSImage(data: Data(contentsOf: url))
    }
```

or

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification)
    {

       let icon = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "RSynchro-Gif"))
       imageGif.image = icon
       imageGif.animates = true
    }
```

None of them works but if I replace the .gif file with a .png, it works.
Anyone to show me the right way?
Thanks.

Comment: How did you add the image to the project? Which statement does not work and how? I tried your code and 1 and 2 work, 3 doesn't.

Comment: I dragged it from the finder inside Assets.xcassets.

Comment: Does the asset catalog support gif?

Comment: Using "add files to..." instead of dragging to asset catalog displayed the first frame of the gif file (using exemple 1) but no further.

Comment: The question now is how to make it switch to next frame. Based on this example for ios (https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif) I understand that I need to find an equivalent to the "animatedImage" UIImage class for mac. I have not find something like that with the test I made using NSImage. Should I try to animate .png files instead? My goal is to animate a icon placed inside the StatusBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(See the edit to my answer below. My initial answer was outdated and therefore wrong.)

I don't believe there is native support for GIF image type in Mac OS. (I know for a fact there isn't in iOS, where I do most of my work these days, and am fairly sure the same holds true for Mac OS. I know Mac OS didn't support GIF as of about 3 years ago.)

### EDIT:

Apparently I'm wrong. It looks like you **can** load the first frame of a GIF image if you put the image in your app's bundle directly rather than into your assets catalog. If you create an image set in your asset catalog and drag a GIF into that it appears to work in Xcode but the image doesn't load. (I tried it for both a Mac app and an iOS app and the results are the same.)

Comment: The asset catalog doesn't support gif, Cocoa does. Edit your answer.

Comment: @Willeke, I guess you're right. I've corrected my answer.